# KeyListener for JLabel don't work for me

Tags: java, eclipse, keylistener

I have a problem with my code when I pressed on the up or down arrow nothing happen.
Here's my code and sorry for my english. 
This is the part for the Racket 1, the part for the Racket 2 id similar.

```
//--->Racket 1 :
    Racket1.addKeyListener(this);
    Racket1.setBounds(50, 200, 16, 100);   //<----- setBounds (Placer position du JLabel x,y + taille de la plateforme x,y)
    Racket1.setBackground(Color.white);
    Racket1.setOpaque(true);
    Racket1.setFocusable(true);            //<----- Permet d'utiliser KeyListener Pour un JLabel
    Racket1.requestFocus();
```

And this is the part of the keyListener :

```
 public void keyTyped (KeyEvent e) {            
  }

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {            


    if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {         
        Racket1.setLocation(Racket1.getX(), Racket1.getY() +20);     
    }           

    else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {          
        Racket1.setLocation(Racket1.getX(), Racket1.getY() -20);            
    }           

    else if (e.getKeyCode() == 'z') {           
        Racket2.setLocation(Racket2.getX(), Racket2.getY() +20);            
    }           

    else if (e.getKeyCode() == 's') {           
        Racket2.setLocation(Racket2.getX(), Racket2.getY() -20);            
    }       
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
```

Comment: What do the rackets do?

Comment: You might want to be a bit more specific about the behavior, and what you've tried.  Have you checked to see if the keyPressed() method is being called at all?

Comment: The rackets are supposed to moove there are the two rackets of a pong game

Comment: macserv I didn't really understand what do u mean by your question (I'm beginer in the programmation)

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a KeyListener. Only one component can have focus at a time, so you will only ever be able to move one of the rackets.

Instead you should be using `KeyBindings`. `Key Bindings` are used to bind an `Action` to a `KeyStroke` and the component doesn't need to have focus.

Check out [Motion Using the Keyboard](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/06/09/motion-using-the-keyboard/) for more information. The `KeyboardAnimation.java` even has an example that uses two labels.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably that the JLabel is not the focus owner. By default, JLabels are not focusable. You need to call

```
yourLabel.setFocusable(true);
yourLabel.requestFocus();
```

And then it should work.

Comment: I did it, my JLabel is focusable I used the functions setFocusable and requestfocus.

Comment: Given there are two rackets you will only be able to move one racket with this approach. Don't use a KeyListener!